# try code reading cp.c but don't understanding

Tags: c, freebsd

I try code reading cp command in FreeBSD.

I'm reading cp.c of FreeBSD.

I don't understand below code.

```
if (to.p_path == to.p_end) {
        *to.p_end++ = '.';
        *to.p_end = 0;
}
```

What purpose this code?
What does effect any situation?

Original Source Code is there.
https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/release/12.0.0/bin/cp/cp.c?revision=341707&view=markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, this reads as

```
if o.p_path == "":
   o.p_path = "."
```

If I understand it right, it makes `cp /somepath/somefile` to work like `cp /somepath/somefile .`

Comment: Thank you your reaction. I have a question. Before that this code check argc value and if argc value is less than 2 this code print usage.

I think situation of follow this code can not occur.

I don't understand this code's purpose.

Comment: Small correction: code applies to commands like cp /foo/bar “”

Comment: I would ask the author or maintainer of the cp source on the proper FreeBSD mailinglist. The have a good working community.